# how can i get the index of an element in array using perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, indexing

To get the index of elements in fields containing /, I use the following but get an error msg:

```
@ind = grep($fields[$_] =~ /\/\/]);
```

Search pattern not terminated

Comment: Also, `grep` should have two parameters, not one: what list are you grepping?

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, here's how it should look like (if array in question is `@fields` variable):

```
my @slash_indexes = grep { $fields[$_] =~ m~/~ } 0..$#fields;
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/63737). The code given in the question misses the second param of [**grep**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) - the list that should be grepped. Considering you need to collect indexes, you need to pass indexes of the original array into `grep` as well, and not the array itself.

Comment: Doesn't work with any of them

Not enough arguments for grep at file.pl line 19, near "/\//)"
Execution of file.pl aborted due to compilation errors.


Not enough arguments for grep at file.pl line 19, near "m#/#)"
Execution of file.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @carol Have you checked the demo, how it's different from your code? Or have you somehow commented on another answer within this one's thread - without actually checking it? )

Comment: this one seems to work but as it was posted even with removing \, didn't

@ind = grep{$fields[$_] =~ /\//} 0..$#fields;

Comment: how can I exclude the 0/0 expressions in the same line,i.e taking all expressions containing / except 0/0

@ind = grep{$fields[$_] =~ /\//} 0..$#fields;

and test in another line

if (grep($colNames[$curr_ind] !~ /0\/0/)){
       print "$colNames[$curr_ind]\t";
}

which doesn't work

Comment: You can combine two expressions in the same block: `grep { $fields[$_] =~ m~/~ && $fields[$_] ne '0/0' }`.

Comment: It's possible to do the same thing with a single regex, but I don't think it'll be more readable. Besides, if you ever happen to need to exclude another set of expressions, it'll be easier to change this code than a single regex.

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping the `/` that should terminate your regular expression.

Just remove the last `\` from before it.

Comment: That's why it's often advantageous to choose another delimiter: `=~ m#/#` is more readable than `=~ /\//`.